# MySQL statement works in phpmyadmin but not in code

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have the following piece of code. It works when executed in the sql interface of phpmyadmin but when I execute it on the server `$stmt = $con->prepare($sql)` always returns false and I exit with an error.

Note that `$stmt = $con->prepare($sql)` does not return an error messages. I'm afraid I might be doing something wrong here too?

I assume I'm missing something important here!

Also the Update statement worked correctly before I modified it to return a comma separated list of updated IDs.

```
$sql = "SET @uids := null;
                    UPDATE userpicks, brackets
                    SET userpicks.player1 = ?, userpicks.pick = ?
                    WHERE userpicks.id_user = ? AND userpicks.id_tournament = ? AND brackets.stage > ? AND userpicks.player1 = ?
                    AND ( SELECT @uids := CONCAT_WS(',', brackets.id, @uids) );
                    SELECT @uids;";

        if ($stmt = $con->prepare($sql)) {
            $stmt->bind_param('iiiiii', $noPlayerID, $noPlayerID, $_SESSION ["id"], $id_tournament, $bracket_stage, $id_player);
        } else {
            echo mysqli_error($con);
            return getJSONArrayError("Error occurred");
        }
```

Comment: you didn't executed your query in your code.

Comment: get the real error http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php should there be any when you execute it

Comment: Query is only executed if prepare was successful. I'm echoing the "real" error already but it is empty.

Comment: You're trying to execute three separate queries in a single call. You can't do that, unless you're using `mysqli_multi_query`.

Comment: I can not use that with prepared statements right?

Comment: @Markus - sadly not; you might have to rethink how the logic of your code works.

Comment: Alright then I'll just select them prior to updating. A bit more hit on the server but I see no other way now. Thanks for claryfing and actually reading my post.

Answer (score -2):

I think you are mixing up Procedural and OOP approach in PHP
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php
Try
$stmt=mysqli->prepare($con,$sql)
instead of
($stmt = $con->prepare($sql))

Comment: That is wrong. `$stmt = mysqli->prepare()` will try to use a method called `prepare` in `mysqli`, but since mysqli isn't an object, it will fail. At the very least, you should be using `$mysql->prepare()`. There's also nothing wrong with mixing procedural and OOP calls, though it does tend to make your code harder to read.